# Getting records but order by not working with union

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables and I am using UNION to get the records from both tables. I am getting the records but records are not displaying in DESC order. I mean order by is not working.

```
(
  select l.c_id,l.companyname, l.c_firstname, l.c_lastname, emp.firstname as empfirstname,emp.lastname as emplastname
  from tbl_lead as l
  inner join tbl_employee as emp on l.createby=emp.id
  WHERE l.leadstatus IN (2,3)
  ORDER BY l.date_of_created DESC
) UNION ALL (
  select l.c_id,l.companyname, l.c_firstname, l.c_lastname, emp.firstname as empfirstname,emp.lastname as emplastname
  from tbl_leadUpload as l
  inner join tbl_employee as emp on l.createby=emp.id
  where l.leadstatus IN (2,3)
  ORDER BY l.date_of_created DESC
)
```

would you help me out with this issue?

Comment: All answers are good guess-works. But from your question alone, it's still not clear what you get, why you think it's wrong and what you want to get instead.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel, I was not getting the records descending order. There was some issue with an order by. After using below answer my issue got resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting each subquery and then applying `UNION ALL` does not mean the result will be sorted.
What you can do is select also the column that you want to order by and apply sorting at the result:

```
select 
  l.date_of_created, l.c_id, l.companyname, l.c_firstname, l.c_lastname, 
  emp.firstname as empfirstname, emp.lastname as emplastname 
from tbl_lead as l inner join tbl_employee as emp 
on l.createby=emp.id 
WHERE l.leadstatus IN (2,3) 
UNION ALL 
select 
  l.date_of_created, l.c_id, l.companyname, l.c_firstname, l.c_lastname, 
  emp.firstname as empfirstname, emp.lastname as emplastname 
from tbl_leadUpload as l inner join tbl_employee as emp 
on l.createby=emp.id 
where l.leadstatus IN (2,3) 
ORDER BY date_of_created DESC
```

or if you don't want to select `date_of_created`:

```
select 
  t.c_id, companyname, t.c_firstname, t.c_lastname, t.empfirstname, t.emplastname
from (
  select 
    l.date_of_created, l.c_id, l.companyname, l.c_firstname, l.c_lastname, 
    emp.firstname as empfirstname, emp.lastname as emplastname 
  from tbl_lead as l inner join tbl_employee as emp 
  on l.createby=emp.id 
  WHERE l.leadstatus IN (2,3) 
  UNION ALL 
  select 
    l.date_of_created, l.c_id, l.companyname, l.c_firstname, l.c_lastname, 
    emp.firstname as empfirstname, emp.lastname as emplastname 
  from tbl_leadUpload as l inner join tbl_employee as emp 
  on l.createby=emp.id 
  where l.leadstatus IN (2,3) 
) as t
ORDER BY t.date_of_created DESC
```

Comment: @forpass, your answer is also working for me. Upvote from my side.Thanks for the help

Comment: oh! I am so sorry, Now I got it, Your answer is the first one.

Answer (score 2):

Take `ORDER BY` Clause to the main subquery to be used commonly for the both of the subqueries :

```
select c_id, companyname, c_firstname, c_lastname, empfirstname, emplastname
  from
  (
   select l.date_of_created,l.c_id,l.companyname, l.c_firstname, l.c_lastname,   
          emp.firstname as empfirstname,emp.lastname as emplastname 
     from tbl_lead as l inner join tbl_employee as emp on l.createby=emp.id 
    where l.leadstatus in (2,3)  
    union all 
   select l.date_of_created,l.c_id,l.companyname, l.c_firstname, l.c_lastname,                        
          emp.firstname as empfirstname,emp.lastname as emplastname 
     from tbl_leadUpload as l inner join tbl_employee as emp on l.createby=emp.id        
    where l.leadstatus in (2,3) 
  ) q
order by date_of_created desc
```

Comment: Give me some time to understand your answer.

Comment: Upvote from my side. Sorry I accept the first answer. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
select l.c_id, l.companyname, l.c_firstname, l.c_lastname, 
       e.firstname as empfirstname, e.lastname as emplastname 
from ((select l.created_by, l.date_of_created, l.c_id, l.companyname, l.c_firstname, l.c_lastname
       from tbl_lead l
       where l.leadstatus in (2, 3)
      ) union all
      (select l.created_by, l.date_of_created, l.c_id, l.companyname, l.c_firstname, l.c_lastname
       from tbl_leadupdate l
       where l.leadstatus in (2, 3)
      )
     ) l join
     tbl_employee as emp 
     on l.createby = emp.id 
order by l.date_of_created desc;
```

If the two "leads" tables have the same columns, even less typing is needed:

```
select l.c_id, l.companyname, l.c_firstname, l.c_lastname, 
       e.firstname as empfirstname, e.lastname as emplastname 
from ((select l.*
       from tbl_lead l
       where l.leadstatus in (2, 3)
      ) union all
      (select l.*
       from tbl_leadupdate l
       where l.leadstatus in (2, 3)
      )
     ) l join
     tbl_employee as emp 
     on l.createby = emp.id 
order by l.date_of_created desc;
```